# Is it possible for loading a Window inside a GridView in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In my task, I need to load a Window inside a GridView in WPF. It looks like MDI in Windows Form C# but I can't find the way for applying to WPF.I've used [WPF MDI](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/), but it seems to create a control looks like Window instead, not the Window tag

Thank you for your support

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Do you have a diagram or screenshot to illustrate your idea? Thanks

Comment: a grid can't be the parent of a window.

Comment: when a window is put inside another window, the role of Window is not important anymore, so just use a Control instead. Looks like in WPF, Window cannot be added to another Window. In Winforms, that's possible if the `TopLevel` is set to `false`.

Comment: Thank you Mr Duncan. Here is an example of MDI form in Windows Form C#. I need to display a Window inside gridview like that example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7571/Creating-MDI-application-using-C-Walkthrough

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, only one windows can be created at a time. So unlike Winform, we can't add Window as a control of parent Window.